# Delphi - how to cut string to given appearance of another string

Tags: string, delphi

I need a function to cut string to given appearance of another string. I tried to do it like that:

```
function substring2(inputText, limitText: String; max: Integer): String;
var
  lastAppearence: Integer;
begin
  lastAppearence := 0;
  for var I := 0 to max - 1 do
  begin
    lastAppearence := inputText.IndexOf(limitText, lastAppearence + I);
    if lastAppearence = -1 then
    begin
      lastAppearence := inputText.Length;
      break
    end;
  end;
  result := inputText.Substring(0, lastAppearence);
end;
```

I think there could be a way to do it simplier or better. Is there any function from basic Delphi Library, or maybe i could do it better some way?

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for position of the las occurrence of some substring then use [LastIndexOf](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.SysUtils.TStringHelper.LastIndexOf) string helper istead of the [IndexOf](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.SysUtils.TStringHelper.IndexOf) that you are using in your code.

This way you avoid the need for having a loop inside your function and can get the desired result with just one line

```
result := inputText.Substring(0, inputText.LastIndexOf(limitText, 0);
```